# Hibernate select query with different where clause

Tags: hibernate, hql

This might be quite simple but I have spent hours in Google but couldn't find a relevant answer.

I am trying to put the below logic into hibernate but i am not able to figure out how.
This is my setup: Mysql database with 2 tables T1(ID,C1,C2) and T2(column1,column2,column3). 
This is what I want to implement

```
    results = select ID, from T1 //This will result in multiple rows.

    for(eachRow in results )
    {
    select column1,column2,column3 from T2 where ID=eachRow.ID
    //Do some computation like
    //Assign value of table "T1" column "C1" to table "T2" column "column1"
    column1 = eachRow.C1

    }
```

For now I could think of a logic of reading the entire table using the Hibernate "from" clause into a List and iterating through it. However this might cause a OutOfMemory exception. Could you please suggest how the HQL must be?

This is what I did

```
Session session = HibernateSession.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction aTableTx = null;
        try {
            aTableTx = session.beginTransaction();

            _allRows = session.createQuery("from T1").list();

            for (Iterator<T1> iterator = _allRows.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
            {
                T1 aRow = iterator.next();
                //Here I am planning to run a similar to
                            //_allRows = session.createQuery("from T2").list();
                            //Store the result and iterate through the list, but 
                            //it is very inefficient.
            }

            aTableTx.commit();
```

Comment: First of all, HQL doesn't work on tables, but on entities. Show us your entities rather than the tables.

Comment: I agree,I have mapped the tables to the class using annotations. So now I have 2 classes T1 and T2 how do I put the above mysql query into HQL.

Comment: The HQL query would be nearly identical to the SQL query. Have you read the documentation about HQL? What have you tried?

Comment: I have edited and added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll to the results of a query, using the `scroll()` (or `iterate()`) method, rather than the `list()` method.

Make sure to regularly flush and clear the session, as explained in the [hibernate documentation of batch updates](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-update).

Also, the inner query should at least have a where clause, as your pseudo-SQL query has one. The two entities should probably be associated with OneToMany or OneToOne column, which would avoid the need for this inner query completely.

I think the best thing to do would be to read the Hibernate documentation.

Answer (score 0):

While Iterating in the T1 table, you can run a query that will have a where clause in it like this:

```
T1 aRow = iterator.next();
Query query= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from T2 as where T2.ID=:aRowID");
query.setInteger("aRowID", aRow.ID);
```